# Error passing spweb and splist variables as function parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splist, spweb

I need to pass `SPWeb` an `SPList` as function parameters:

```
string check(SPWeb web1, SPList splist1){}
```

Yet, `web1.Title`, `splist1.Title` throws errors:

> There is no Web named "/http://DevSite".

Is there another way to get this variables? by passing as a reference?

Comment: how are you creating `SPWeb` object? Its seems problem with the way you are initializing these objects.

Comment: yes ! you are right! The error was at the calling function !!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the calling function. Before:

```
using (SPWeb web11 = spsite.OpenWeb(webURL))
    {
      if (web11 != null)
         {
            spweb = web11; <-- error
            splist = spweb.GetList(paramwebURL);
          }
     }
return check(spweb,sptitle);
```

The correct is :  spweb = spsite.OpenWeb(webURL); For (unknown to me) reason, assignment between SPWeb's didn't worked